# What part on this gate opener PCB is used for communication with the gate's antenna?

Tags: pcb, antenna, pcb-antenna

I am working on a project where I want to integrate my gate opener into a 5V car input device, to where when I get close to the gate it opens automatically without me needing to press a button.

I have never worked with electronics to this level and I am basically starting from scratch.

So better start asking questions and learning, right?

Anyways, what part on this garage door opener PCB actually sends out the signal to the gate antenna?  What form of radio signal is it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site :-) Just to avoid this being an XY-problem, please can you explain why you care about the RF signal? If you are going to integrate that gate opener into something else, then the easiest way to integrate is to put that whole PCB into the other device, and switch the power to the whole gate opener (via its battery terminals) or by adding a parallel connection to its onboard switch (S1) - none of that requires knowledge of the RF signal. So please can you [Edit] your question and explain more context of why the details of the RF signal are important to you. Thanks.

Comment: Very interesting circuit you have found there. A very small foundry listing "MCMOS ASIC Garage Door Opener" on their website under capabilities. If the frequency is high enough and the range short enough, the antenna may be fully integrated inside the IC.

Comment: If you are thinking about applying power to the circuit during the whole period that the car is being driven (in case you happen to be driving close to your gate) then it might be illegal to do so and, the fob electronics may not actually survive an extended period of power being applied.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This U-shaped track on the underside is the antenna (nothing else can explain the presence of C3).

The signal is probably On-Off Keying (OOK) at the frequency on the nameplate.

The OOK modulating signal generated by what appears to be a trinary encoder chip (like has traditionally been used for garage remotes)

Answer (score 1):

Jasen has identified the likely antenna of the transmitter. It is also an inductor of the oscillator - any alteration of this track would change the frequency, and render the radio link inoperative. All the oscillator components within the block labeled **Transmitter** shown below should be left unaltered:
[image]
The resistor with label **R1** connects the serial digital code to the transmitter, turning it on and off: (OOK type keying).

Switch S1 continues to enable the serial code sequence to be transmitted as long as it is depressed. This switch must be depressed for a short time, to allow at least one serial sequence to be transmitted. If you want to enable this transmitter to send its signal, this is where you'd interface.
A N-channel MOSfet might be added in parallel with S1. The battery's negative terminal is the "ground" reference point for turning the MOSfet **on** or **off**.

- Raising its gate terminal to +5V with respect to the battery negative terminal does the same as depressing S1: a radio signal is transmitted.
- When the gate terminal is at 0V with respect to the battery negative terminal, the whole transmitter and serial encoder is idle.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXZ6Qx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This helps a lot!